# Setting different checkout repo location for Gitlab CI-CD other than host machine

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I need to set the checkout repo path for the GitLab runner to the docker or other machine instead repo machine.

Is it possible in Gitlab CI/CD?

Example:

Repo path - https://xxx.gitlab.com

Docker runner machine Name - XXX_Runner

Check-out repo-name needs to be - **smb://XXX_Runner/Users/XXX/builds** or anything maps this machine name with path.